# C++ member function using another member function

Tags: c++, class, oop, member

I'm facing a big issue which I have been trying to solve in vain for 3 days. I've got a `CDS` class with a `intensity_func` member function and a `big_gamma` member function which is basically the integral of the member `intensity_func` function.

```
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std   

class CDS
{
public:
    CDS(); 
    CDS(double notional, vector<double> pay_times, vector<double> intensity);
    ~CDS(); 


 double m_notional; 
 vector<double> m_paytimes;
 vector<double> m_intensity;

 double intensity_func(double);

 double big_gamma(double);

};
```

And here is the CDS.cpp with the definition of the `intensity_func` member function :

```
#include <vector>
#include <random>
#include <cmath>

#include "CDS.h"

double CDS::intensity_func(double t)
{
    vector<double> x = this->m_intensity;
    vector<double> y = this->m_paytimes;
    if(t >= y.back() || t< y.front())
    {
        return 0;
    }

    else
    {
        int d=index_beta(y, t) - 1;
        double result = x.at(d) + (x.at(d+1) - x.at(d))*(t - y.at(d))/ (y.at(d+1) - y.at(d));
        return result;
    }
```

I have implemented in another source file a function to integrate function and the `index_beta` function used in the `intensity_func` member function (using the Simpson's rule). Here is the code:

```
double simple_integration ( double (*fct)(double),double a, double b) 
{
       //Compute the integral of a (continuous) function on [a;b]
       //Simpson's rule is used
       return (b-a)*(fct(a)+fct(b)+4*fct((a+b)/2))/6;
};


double integration(double (*fct)(double),double a, double b, double N) 
{
       //The integral is computed using the simple_integration function
       double sum = 0;
       double h = (b-a)/N;
       for(double x = a; x<b ; x = x+h) {
             sum += simple_integration(fct,x,x+h);
       }
       return sum;
};

int index_beta(vector<double> x, double tau)
{
    // The vector x is sorted in increasing order and tau is a double


    if(tau < x.back())
    {
        vector<double>::iterator it = x.begin();
        int n=0;

        while (*it < tau)
        {
            ++ it;
            ++n; // or n++;
        }
        return n;
    }

    else
    {
        return x.size();
    }


};
```

So, what I would like to have in my `CDS.cpp` to define the big_gamma member function is :

```
double CDS::big_gamma(double t)
{
    return  integration(this->intensity, 0, t);
};
```

But obviously, it does not work and I get the following error message : `reference to non static member function must be called`. I've then tried to turn the `intensity` member function into a static function but new problems come out: I can't used `this->m_intensity` and `this->m_paytimes` anymore as I get the following error message: `Invalid use of this outside a non-static member function`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`double (*fct)(double)` declares an argument of type "pointer-to-function". You need to declare that as a "pointer-to-member function" instead: `double (CDS::*fct)(double)`. Furthermore, you need an object on which you call the pointer-to-member:

```
(someObject->*fct)(someDouble);
```

Comment: But in my main.cpp when using the integration function with for example the sinus function double sinus(double x) {return sin(x);};, it works perfectly.

Comment: @marino89 - exactly right. `sinus` is an ordinary function, and you point to it with a pointer-to-function. `intensity` is a member function, and you point to it with a pointer-to-member function.

Comment: Ok, So what I need to do is : `double CDS::big_gamma(double t)
{
    
    double (CDS::*fptr)(double);
    fptr= &CDS::intensity_func;
    return  integration(fprt, 0, t,1000);
};`. The problem is that I'm not using as you said a object to call the pointer-to-member. What kind of object do I need?